# In asp.net images show on default page only

Tags: asp.net, image, default

The image shows in default.aspx when I save the page as link1.aspx and make no other changes it shows alt text, not the image.

```js
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="bottom">
<img src="/images/default_home.gif" alt="home" width="140" height="90" border="0" name="topLink9"
usemap="#default9Map" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="images/default_link1.gif" alt="" width="140" height="60" border="0" name="topLink1"
usemap="#default1Map" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you put up the code for your page? Especially the image and it's context? And when you save it as link1.aspx, do you save it in the same folder?

Comment: No the default.aspx is in the root folder and link1.aspx is in the 'Pages' folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use server controls for images you could use "~" to notate "relative to root" path.  The issue you are seeing are due to the paths being relative to the calling page.

If your structure is like:

```
root
root/images
root/default.aspx
root/pages/link1.aspx
```

from `root/default.aspx` the path `/images/default_home.gif` points too `root/images/default_home.gif`.

WHen in the `root/pages/link1.aspx` the same path `/images/default_home.gif` points to `root/pages/images/default_home.gif` - which is not a valid path.

You can use server control images as such:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgId" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/default_home.gif" />
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining in more detail

Answer (score 1):

Your images are using relative paths which will break if the webpage is in a subdirectory, which sounds like the problem you're having.

Judging by the fact you're using long-deprecated presentational attributes in your HTML I'm assuming you're using ASP.NET WebForms, in which case just apply `runat="server"` to your `<img />` elements and use the special root-relative syntax:

```
<img runat="server" src="~/images/default_home.gif" />
```